# How can I use the pyodbc library in python to successfully upload an Attachment(s) to my Access Database?

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

So I am using the pyodbc library in python to access my Microsoft Access Database and was simply trying to insert data in the fields I created, with one of the fields being an Attachments Type column. As such I was trying to find a way to insert Attachments into my accdb through python.

This is my code, where I have successfully been able to connect to my database.
This is what I was using to try to insert the text and the attachments; I put it as a combined string separated by semicolons as that is the output I would get if I selected and printed the values in the Attachment column:
[My Code for setting up a connection, getting the info from a database if it exists, and trying to insert both textual data and attachment data to a database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxNbl.png)

However, after running, I get this error and no fields are populated:[Error generated for Insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm2aT.png)

So my question, to rephrase is: How can I use the pyodbc library in python to successfully upload an Attachment(s) to my Access Database?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I use the pyodbc library in python to successfully upload an Attachment(s) to my Access Database?

You can't. The Access ODBC driver does not support inserting files to an Attachment field. Therefore, you cannot use pyodbc to do it.

> I was trying to find a way to insert Attachments into my accdb through python.

You *can* insert files into an Attachment field using Python, but you need to use Access DAO to do it. You might be able to use [win32com](https://superuser.com/q/609447/207964) with "standard" Python (I've never tried it), or you could use [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) and manipulate Access DAO through the .NET Framework.

IronPython example:

```python
# Example table: [MyTable]
# 
# ID - AutoNumber, Primary Key
# AttachedFiles - Attachment
# 
# 
# Add an attachment to an existing row where ID=1

import System
t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DAO.DBEngine.120")
dbe = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t)
db = dbe.OpenDatabase(r"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb")
rs_main = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT AttachedFiles FROM MyTable WHERE ID=1", 2)  # dbOpenDynaset
rs_main.Edit()
rs_attach = rs_main.Fields["AttachedFiles"].Value
rs_attach.AddNew()
fld = rs_attach.Fields["FileData"]  # "magic" field name for Attachments
fld.LoadFromFile(r"C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\sample.pdf")
rs_attach.Update()
rs_attach.Close()
rs_main.Update()
rs_main.Close()
db.Close()
```

Comment: Just an update by the way, i did what you said and was able to get this working using win32com using the example you provided, so thank you very much for the assist. Literally, the only differences between my code and yours are the win32com module usage and a few functions.